Brightness Not changing
I have my brand new laptop ASUS A15 AMD Ryzen 7.Its dual boot with Windows 11 and Ubuntu 24.04.Inn windows brightness is working fine.But in ubuntu its not changing by pressing keys or changing the slider or using commands.
I have tried almost everything from the internet.I changed the grub files several times from different solutions.I've downloaded new kernel 6.12 before it was 6.8.Still its not working.What to do ?
Someone please help
